# Evaluate filter matlab function using python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

Based on the description of both functions, `filter(b, a, x)` matlab function and `lfilter(b, a, x, axis=-1, z_i=None)` scipy.signal should give the same result.

I take this example where the results are completely different:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter

bb = np.arange(0, 100, 1)

aa = 1

xx = np.tile(0.9, (100, 1))

yy = lfilter(b=bb, a=aa, x=xx)

print(yy[:10])

array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
print(yy.shape)
(100, 1)

# Same example on Matlab using filter
bb = 0:1:99
aa  =  1
xx =repmat(0.9, 100, 1)
dd = filter(bb, aa, xx)
dd(1:10)
ans =

         0
    0.9000
    2.7000
    5.4000
    9.0000
   13.5000
   18.9000
   25.2000
   32.4000
   40.5000
print(size(dd)) # (100 ,1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB and NumPy handle array shapes differently.  NumPy has general n-dimensional arrays.  `scipy.signal.lfilter` accepts an n-dimensional array, and applies the filter along each 1-d slice of the input array.  *Which* slice is determined by the `axis` parameter.  By default, `lfilter` operates on the *last* axis (`axis=-1`).  You gave `lfilter` an array with shape (100, 1).  Applying `lfilter` with `axis=-1` to that input applies the filter 100 times, once for each row of length 1--certainly not what you want!  Instead, you want to apply the filter along `axis=0` (which in this 2-d case, means apply `lfilter` along the columns).  If you change the call of `lfilter` to

```
yy = lfilter(b=bb, a=aa, x=xx, axis=0)
```

the values returned will match those of the MATLAB code.

In the long term, I recommend not limiting yourself to 2-d arrays.  In this case, it makes more sense to create `xx` as a 1-d array (e.g. `xx = np.full(100, fill_value=0.9)`). Then `lfilter` will operate on the given 1-d array the way you expect, without having to specify the `axis`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @warren is good. Here are more details about the use of functions.

`filter(b, a, x, zi, dim)` return `zf` value even if `zi` is not given as input.

In the example above:

```
[y, zf] = filter(b=bb, a=aa, x=xx)

zf(1:10)

ans =

   1.0e+03 *

    4.4550
    4.4541
    4.4523
    4.4496
    4.4460
    4.4415
    4.4361
    4.4298
    4.4226
    4.4145
```

However in `lfilter(a, b, x, zi=None, axis=-1)`, to get the `zf`, you have to provide `zi`. For that, you can use, `lfilter_zi(b, x)` that construct initial conditions for `lfilter` for step response steady-state.

```
z_i = lfilter_zi(b=bb, a=aa)
y, zf = lfilter(b=bb, x=xx, a=aa, zi=z_i, axis=0)

zf[1:10]

[[4455. ]
 [4454.1]
 [4452.3]
 [4449.6]
 [4446. ]
 [4441.5]
 [4436.1]
 [4429.8]
 [4422.6]
 [4414.5]]
```